# How I can imply that the supremum is in a set S?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove this:

Let $S$ be a nonempty set of real numbers that ins bounded from above (below) and let $x=sup S(infS)$.Prove that either $x$ belongs to $S$ or $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

And then I have that:

For this prove we will assume that $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$. 
Since $S$ is not empty and is bounded from above then $S$ has a least greater bound, let $x=sups$.

But I do not know how can I imply that $x \in S$, and another question is: Do I have to prove that if $x$ is not in $S$ then $x$ is an accumulation point? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to proceed.

Comment: Thank you @HagenvonEitzen But I do not know how can I imply that x∈S, and  Do I have to prove that if x is not in S then x is an accumulation point? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\sup S$ is in $S$, then you are done.

Suppose $x$ is not in $S$. We argue now that $x$ is an accumulation point. By definition, it is enough to argue that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a point $z\neq x$ such that $z\in S$ and $z$ lies in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$. To this end, note that $x-\epsilon<x$ and because $x$ is the *least* upper bound of $S$, there is $z\in S$ such that $z>x-\epsilon$. Because $z\in S$, you have $z\leq x$ so that $z\in(x-\epsilon,x]\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. Finally, because $z$ is in $S$ and $x$ is not, $z\neq x$.

Comment: I have a question @KimJongUn , do this involve the two questions ?, or I have to prove something else? :) thank you.

Comment: Basically, you are asked to prove either $A$ or $B$. In this situation, it's enough to show that if $A$ isn't true, then $B$ must be. If you were referring to the fact that question mentioned both $\sup$ and $\inf$, then note that $\inf S=-\sup(-S)$. You can also practice by replicating the argument above for $\inf$. (Hint: if $y=\inf S$, think about $y<y+\epsilon$.)

Comment: Ok thank you @KimJongUn then it is enough in this case but in further cases do I need to prove something else?

Comment: I think the best thing to do is if you have other *specific* concerns, post them in another question. Cheers.